# Video frame doesn't change for first 12 seconds when starting video

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I'm using live streaming with a simple iOS test application which uses a MPMoviePlayerController. I am running this on the iOS Simulator 7.1, XCode 5.1. I don't have a physical device to test against right now.

The stream is on the local network but accessed over WiFi. The live stream is generated with VLC like this:

```
vlc -I dummy rtsp://media1.law.harvard.edu/Media/policy_a/2012/02/02_unger.mov vlc://quit --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=512,scale=1,acodec=none,venc=x264{preset=ultrafast,aud,profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=5,bframes=0,ref=1},acodec=aac,ab=128}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,index=/tmp/streaming/mystream.m3u8,index-url=http://192.168.254.4/mystream-########.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/tmp/streaming/mystream-########.ts}'
```

When I start playing the stream, I can hear the sound almost instantly and see a frame of the video on the screen which is frozen; after about twelve seconds the video starts playing normally and everything is fine thereafter. There are no errors in the console.

I can see iOS requesting the stream index file and then the stream files when the app loads - so it is requesting the files OK.

I thought that this may have something to do with iOS preferring to use a lower bitrate initially before switching up to a higher bit rate based on available bandwidth, as I've read about in the docs.

If I point the MPMoviePlayerController at the following apple test stream then it plays instantly and seems to use a lower quality stream first for about twelve seconds before switching to higher quailty/bitrate:
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

I tried presenting a .m3u8 file that contained multiple bit rates like the apple example but it behaves in the same way with the frozen frame but just at a lower bitrate for twelve seconds, plays low-res for about 2-5 seconds then the screen goes blank for a while and then switches over to the high bit rate - audio can be heard the entire time. There are errors in the console for playback stall.

Does anyone know the cause of the frozen video frame and how to resolve it and have it play smoothly from the start?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by compiling latest version of FFmpeg using their instructions:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

As FFMpeg can do everything we need with HLS support can also lose the VLC part.

```
~/bin/ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://media1.law.harvard.edu/Media/policy_a/2012/02/02_unger.mov -hls_time 10 /tmp/streaming/mystream.m3u8
```